# Conditional Pandas combined with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, gps

I have quite an interesting problem. I have a data frame containing data of a car that is triggered by events in the GPS. The data also contains GPS data. However, I have made a Polygon in Matplot that I want to limit my GPS data. With other words, I am trying filter out data that has been recorded inside of the Polygon that has been created with GPS points. I have tried solving this problem by first adding a new column with a built in condition in matplotlib (`poly_path.contains_point(point)`).

My GPS column looks like this:

GPS DATA:

```
GPS
(57.723124, 11.923557)
(57.724115, 11.933557)
(57.723124, 11.923557)
...
```

And I would like to add a new column using this condition.

GPS DATA:

```
GPS                    Is inside Polygon
(57.723124, 11.923557) True
(57.724115, 11.933557) False
(57.723124, 11.923557) True
...
```

And I have tried solving this problem by adding this line:

```
df1filt["Is inside Polygon"] = poly_path.contains_point(df1filt['GPS'])
```

However doesnt work.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df1filt["Is inside Polygon"] = df1filt['GPS'].apply(poly_path.contains_point)
```

Edit:

If the data type of the column is string, you need to create a cleaning function, apply it, then try my first solution.

E.g.

```
def clean_gps_col(text):
    text = text[1:-1]
    text = text.split(',')
    return (float(text[0]), float(text[1]))

df1filt['GPS_cleaned'] = df1filt['GPS'].apply(clean_gps_col)
```

now try the first soluton

```
df1filt["Is inside Polygon"] = df1filt['GPS_cleaned'].apply(poly_path.contains_point)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, doesnt work. I get the error:
```TypeError: must be real number, not str```

Comment: @LeoWahlbeck What's the datatype required for the function contains_point?

Comment: What you need to do is to have a point in this format:
```point=(1,1)```
I have created a column that has the coordinates in this exact format as a string, do I need to convert the column?

Comment: So a tuple I guess

Comment: @LeoWahlbeck The problem maybe is that your GPS column's data type is string, and not tuple. If so, you need to convert the data first before applying the solution I provided. To do so, you may use some pre-processing techniques or just regex.

Comment: @LeoWahlbeck I have modified the original answer to show you the cleaning function.